# HTML canvas minimum image resize results in distorted image

Tags: canvas, svg, image-resizing

I have a html canvas with resized images. Images are resized from 10-40% which shouldn't be a problematic like if you resize a image for more than 50%.

Yet the image ended up distorted.

[image]

The image above is magnified few times for easier explanation.

The first image is the result of resizing, the second one is how the image should look like. My first idea was creating SVG images but they dont even show correct when not resized. I guess canvas dont suport SVG that well.

I created jsfidle sample [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5xy2mLrp/9/) (pay attention to top left corner )

Is there any way to resize image properly or should i resize in photoshop for every single one?

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// širina canvasa
 ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth-23;
 ctx.canvas.height = 80;


ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle="#b0b0b0";
ctx.fill();

  // resized image - wwrong
  var imgorg = new Image();
    imgorg.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imgorg,0, 10,30,30);
    }
     imgorg.src = 'http://vetercek.com/master3/img/vanish/50/v0.png';

// how the image should look like
  var imgorg2 = new Image();
    imgorg2.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imgorg2,0, 30);
    }
     imgorg2.src = 'http://vetercek.com/master3/img/vanish/30/v0.png';

 // SVG sample without resize   - also wrong
  var imgorg3 = new Image();
    imgorg3.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imgorg3,0, 60);
    }
     imgorg3.src = 'http://vetercek.com/master3/img/vanish/30/v0.svg';
```

Comment: Canvas uses the GPU to render images. When you scale up (or down) it will create artifacts. It is unavoidable, pixels are discrete units and you can not make one pixel fit one and a half pixels without making some approximations of what it should look like.

Comment: Even without passing it through the canvas, your images don't look the same for me (not the same amount of black lines in it), and your svg version is just two parallels lines.

Comment: Thank you both for answering. @Kaiido the images should be the same. I created png from svg. But you are right there are only two black lines and one white in the middle. What about if i create another canvas draw image there save it and restore it later? It could work right ? I drawn the object in jsfidle https://jsfiddle.net/2bv0vyab/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that drawing object in canvas was the right choice. It can be than dynamicly "resized" so there is no quality loss. Object was first drawn to hidden canvas and then on the visible one.

https://jsfiddle.net/5xy2mLrp/11/

```
//magnification
var pov=0.2;

// znak1
var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasPattern.width = 200*pov;canvasPattern.height = 200*pov;
var contextPattern = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");

// sign1
contextPattern.beginPath();
contextPattern.moveTo(95*pov,61.5*pov); contextPattern.lineTo(95*pov,138.5*pov);contextPattern.closePath();
contextPattern.lineWidth=2*pov;contextPattern.strokeStyle = 'black';contextPattern.stroke();
contextPattern.beginPath();
contextPattern.moveTo(98*pov,61.5*pov); contextPattern.lineTo(98*pov,138.5*pov);contextPattern.closePath();
contextPattern.lineWidth=4*pov;contextPattern.strokeStyle = 'white';contextPattern.stroke(); contextPattern.beginPath();
contextPattern.moveTo(100*pov,61.5*pov);contextPattern.lineTo(100*pov,138.5*pov);contextPattern.closePath();
contextPattern.lineWidth=2*pov;contextPattern.strokeStyle = 'black';contextPattern.stroke();


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// širina canvasa
 ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth-23;
 ctx.canvas.height = 80;


ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle="#808080";
ctx.fill();


ctx.drawImage(canvasPattern,30, 30);
```